# cucumber-android unable to find step definitions in project (MissingStepDefinitionError)

Tags: android, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to use Cucumber-JVM in my Android project.
I can run the examples just fine (`android-test` and `cukeulator-test`).

When I introduce cucumber-android into my own Maven project, I get the below `MissingStepDefinitionError`.  It's as if cucumber-android doesn't know where to find its steps.  Originally I thought that the `org.picocontainer.paranamer.NullParanamer` was causing the issue, but the example projects also have this error and they run just fine.  So that could be a red herring.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Maven output:

```
[INFO] Device 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 found.
[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :   Running instrumentation tests in com.myapp.tests
[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :     Run started: com.myapp.tests, 1 tests:
[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :       Start [1/1]: Feature Test#Scenario Testing
[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :       ERROR:Feature Test#Scenario Testing
[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :       cucumber.runtime.android.MissingStepDefinitionError:

@When("^I test$")
public void i_test() throws Throwable {
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
throw new PendingException();
}

at cucumber.runtime.android.AndroidInstrumentationReporter.endOfScenarioLifeCycle(AndroidInstrumentationReporter.java:146)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:179)
at $Proxy2.endOfScenarioLifeCycle(Native Method)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:52)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:116)
at cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentationCore.onStart(CucumberInstrumentationCore.java:131)
at cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation.onStart(CucumberInstrumentation.java:21)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)

[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :       End [1/1]: Feature Test#Scenario Testing
[INFO] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :     Run ended: 0 ms
[ERROR] 015d46d41a300612_asus_Nexus7 :     FAILURES!!!
[INFO]   Tests run: 1,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-android</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Logcat output:

```
03-31 14:14:19.511  17089-17089/? D/cucumber-android﹕ Found CucumberOptions in class com.myapp.tests.MyActivitySteps
03-31 14:14:19.511  17089-17089/? D/cucumber-android﹕ @cucumber.api.CucumberOptions(dotcucumber=, dryRun=false, features=[features], format=[], glue=[], monochrome=false, name=[], snippets=UNDERSCORE, strict=false, tags=[])
...
03-31 14:14:20.401  17089-17104/? D/cucumber-android﹕ Feature: Test (features/helloworld.feature)
03-31 14:14:20.411  17089-17104/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.picocontainer.paranamer.NullParanamer', referenced from method org.picocontainer.paranamer.AnnotationParanamer.<init>
03-31 14:14:20.421  17089-17104/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2070 (Lorg/picocontainer/paranamer/NullParanamer;) in Lorg/picocontainer/paranamer/AnnotationParanamer;
03-31 14:14:20.421  17089-17104/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
03-31 14:14:20.421  17089-17104/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x29a6 at 0x02 in Lorg/picocontainer/paranamer/AnnotationParanamer;.<init>
03-31 14:14:20.441  17089-17104/com.sbg.mobile.tablet D/cucumber-android﹕ Scenario: Testing
03-31 14:14:20.441  17089-17104/com.sbg.mobile.tablet D/cucumber-android﹕ Given I have a test
03-31 14:14:20.441  17089-17104/com.sbg.mobile.tablet D/cucumber-android﹕ When I test
03-31 14:14:20.461  17089-17104/com.sbg.mobile.tablet W/cucumber-android﹕ @Given("^I have a test$")
    public void i_have_a_test() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
    }
03-31 14:14:20.461  17089-17104/com.sbg.mobile.tablet W/cucumber-android﹕ @When("^I test$")
    public void i_test() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
    }
```

Comment: My steps are of course defined in com.myapp.tests.MyActivitySteps.java as per the example projects.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem through trial and error.

First tried moving my step definitions from `src/main` to `src/test` but that didn't help.

What eventually worked was to make sure that the step defs are **not in the same class which is annotated** with `@CucumberOptions`.  It doesn't make sense because this is how the examples are set up and they work OK.  But in my project, step definitions aren't picked up if they're in the class with the options annotation.  Another Java class in the same package is fine.

Bit of a strange one.

Comment: Yeah, most examples on the web are outdated.